# Mod-Rewrite robots.txt for a subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a domain pointed to ex: www.website.com, and a subdomain app.website.com.

Both point to the same folder which contains a wordpress that is shared between the site and the app, and depending on how you arrive, you are directed to the template that will display the proper layout.

I don't want app.website.com to be indexed by the search engines.

I would like to know if there is a way to do a mod-rewrite for robots.txt to send the crawlers to robots-subdomain.txt if they arrive via app.website.com.

---

**Possibly something like this:**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^app.website.com$
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ robots-subdomain.txt
```

**Then include this in the robots-subdomain.txt file.**

```
User-agent: *

Disallow: /
```

---

I have tried variations of this with no success and I am hoping someone with more experience could suggest a better solution.

Chris

Comment: Rule is fine. Make sure it is **before** any wordpress related rules

Comment: moving the code: (RewriteEngine On) to the 1st line and placing my two lines below it, followed by wordpress rules, solved my problem.  Thanks Jon Lin